# How to access outer class non-final variable from inner class in a Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Here is my scenario.

I am making a `listview` extending a `ArrayAdapter` class. In that class I am making a text and a check box dynamically. In that view I want to capture what check box clicked by user.

Here is my `ArrayAdapter` class's `getView` method......

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_category_type_save, null);

        categoryName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_name_save);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);

        categoryName.setText(categoryDeatils.get(position).get("Categoryname"));

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                /// below line of code gives error
                String a = categoryDeatils.get(position).get("Categoryname");


                }
            }
        });

        return v;

    }
```

My question is how I access non-final variable with in the inner class.(Because in `getView` method the `position` variable is non final and it change dynamically)

Comment: add final key word before this variable (int position) in getView.

Comment: in order to access `position` in inner class you must have to declare `position` as `final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare position as final in getView() :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Comment: @Dev513,Glad to help you